# Using AutoLayout to grow a view based on dynamic text in subview

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

I'm working on an app that supports dynamic type. I have a simple UIView that is used as the footer in a table. Within that view is just a UIButton. When the user increases the dynamic type size, the text in the button's label grows, and I need the button itself, and the containing view to both grow appropriately. How can I achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Is the UIButton a custom button class, or are you using the standard class? If it's a standard button setting a preferred font on the `titleLabel` should automatically increase / decrease the font size for the users selected settings. For the footer to grow, you could then set top and bottom constraints around the button in a footer view. Then either return its current size or I think Apple added dynamic footers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIButton` class has an *intrinsic size*, meaning that if you don't constrain it to a specific size it will size itself to a size that will fit its content. This also means that you can tie your button to the edges of a parent `UIView` and let the button control the size of the parent. This will happen automatically as long as you don't explicitly constrain the size of the `UIButton` or `UIView`.

If you want to, you can choose to set a constraint on one axis and have the button control the size of the other, for example let the button control the height of your footer, but always use a fixed width for the footer. In this case you add constraints to the width or left/right of your footer.

[Read more on controls that supports intrinsic sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW21)

[image]

If you need space around the button label you can add it by increasing the content insets.

[image]